# Execution order of CASE statement SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, insert, case

Does a `CASE` statement that has multiple parts that is part of an `INSERT`statement execute in order and do the 'rules' for lack of a better word stay in place even after the next line?  in the query below, does the PO_TYPE assignment overrule the next command - to look in a list of articles for example?  So even if that article was in the list in the second part of the statement if it was type 05 or 07 it will still assign to Andrew?

Thanks.

```
/*INSERT values into the table using SELECT making sure to exclude vendor 20800 - (see last line of code)*/

INSERT INTO SCM_PO_EMPLOYEE_NAME (PO_NUMBER, PO_ITEM_NUMBER, MATERIAL, BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE,PO_TYPE,TEAM_MEMBER_NAME)

                                  SELECT I.PO_NUMBER, 
                                         I.PO_ITEM_NUMBER, 
                                         I.MATERIAL,
                                         B.BU_CODE, 
                                         H.PO_TYPE,
                                         CASE WHEN H.PO_TYPE IN ('05','07') -- Promo PO type - should be on both po type and stock category
                                              AND  I.STOCK_CATEGORY LIKE ('A60383%') -- stock category is second part of the check
                                              THEN 'AZ'
                                              WHEN H.PO_TYPE = '02' -- ma PO type
                                              THEN 'MB'
                                              WHEN I.MATERIAL IN ( SELECT ARTICLE
                                                                   FROM   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED.dbo.SCM_EMPLOYEE_ARTICLE A ) -- Check the Employee to article table next
                                              THEN A.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME -- If the PO number matches that conditions then assign the employee from the employee article table
                                              WHEN M.BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE = B.BU_CODE -- if not use then go to the BU assignment (below)
                                              THEN B.TEAM_MEMBER_NAME  --- Use the team member name from the Employee_BU table
                                         END  AS   [TEAM_MEMBER_NAME]

                                  FROM   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_HEADER H
                                  JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_PO_ITEM I ON H.PO_NUMBER = I.PO_NUMBER 
                                  JOIN   PDX_SAP_USER.dbo.VW_MM_MATERIAL M ON I.MATERIAL = M.MATERIAL 
                                  JOIN   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED.dbo.SCM_EMPLOYEE_ARTICLE A ON I.MATERIAL = A.ARTICLE
                                  JOIN   ADI_USER_MAINTAINED.dbo.SCM_EMPLOYEE_BU B ON B.BU_CODE = M.BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE


                                  WHERE H.VENDOR_NO <> '20800'; --Exclude '20800' as a vendor!!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A `case` *expression* is evaluated sequentially.

So, the second `then` is only evaluated when the first `then` does not return true.  As an extreme example of this, consider:

```
select (case when 1=1 then 'true'
             when 1/0 = 0 then 'error'
        end)
```

This returns `'true'` instead of error'ing out.

Comment: one question I have based on my SQL is, my 3 THEN's are looking at different data - so H.PO_TYPE, I.MATERIAL and M.BUSINESS_UNIT_CODE are not related.  the only objective is to assign a team member if those 3 situations arise, in that particular order - does that change things?

Comment: @user3496218 . . . The `case` expression is evaluated in order.  The conditions don't make a difference.  First the first one, then the second, and so on.

Comment: thanks again.  Here is the question rephrased just to make sure I am getting it correct - if that first condition is met, no matter what happens after it - that is precedent and that employee will always be assigned to that PO type no matter what happens downstream in the CASE?  The article on Andrews PO could be on the article list, but it will never be marked other than Andrew because of that first rule - likewise, an article in the second part - that is contained in that list will now never be assigned to anybody but the employee in that table?

Comment: @user3496218 . . . You got it.  The `case` expression is sequential.