# can we set multiple values in variable in sql

Tags: sql, sql-server

```
DECLARE @a int  
SET @a = 5 

SET @a = CASE
            WHEN @a >= 5 THEN 1 
            WHEN @a <= 5 THEN 2 
            WHEN a < 10 THEN 3 
         END

SELECT @a
```

`@a` value should be 3, but why it is showing 1?

Can anyone explain how it works?

I have been asked same question one of SQL interview

Comment: case returns the result of the first condition that is true. in your case :), it is 1, Try switching the conditions around (eg. put @a < 10 first)

Comment: The [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql) states that a T-SQL searched `CASE`  expression (there is no case statement in T-SQL), "Returns result_expression of the first Boolean_expression that evaluates to TRUE".

Comment: A `case` expression is evaluated sequentially.

So, the second then is only evaluated when the first then does not return true

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Execution order of CASE statement SQL Server](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46626526/execution-order-of-case-statement-sql-server)

Answer (score 0):

`Case` expression will Evaluates, as order you specified :

So, you want prioritized `when` clause  :

```
case when @a < 10 then 3 
     when @a <= 5 then 2 
     when @a >= 5 then 1 
end
```

Comment: thanks for response @Yogesh...I want to know if any variable satisfied all condition like this screnio then varible should hold last value according to condition not first condition value

Comment: This would never return 2 though, and would only return 1 for values of 10 or more. Therefore the second `WHEN` isn't needed.

Comment: @swatikumari. . . as you order defined (`when` clause). In this case you defined `3`.

Comment: @YogeshSharma: if one or more condition are true then variable value will overwrite or it will persist only first met condition value?..that want to confirm in detail

Comment: @swatikumari. . . Returns the value of the first expression that evaluates to `TRUE`. That will not overwrites. You can check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/case-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#return-types

Comment: @YogeshSharma:thanks that's my answer ......if first condition is  true no matter how many more condition are true ..it will show only first meeting condition value .Am i right?

Answer (score 0):

> The CASE statement goes through conditions and returns a value when the first condition is met. Following two way of your problem should be solved, you can try one of them.

```
   declare @a int  

   set @a=5 
   set @a= case when  @a>5 then 1
   when @a<5 then 2 
   when @a <10 then 3 end 
   select @a


   set @a=5 
   set @a= case when @a <10 then 3
   when  @a>=5 then 1
   when @a<=5 then 2 end 
   select @a
```